# Unidentifiable negative sign (-) resulting from U-substitution

Tags: integration, physics, substitution

I am working with General Forced Response for vibrations and I am trying to establish an easy procedure for solving integrals such as the one below.

$$
\int_{0}^{t}\tau\,
\sin\left(\,{\omega_{n}\left[\,{t - \tau}\,\right]}\,\right)\,\mathrm{d}\tau
$$

A quick conclusion is that first utilizing u-substitution, such that $u = (t - τ)$, is a good place to start to make things simpler with partial integration and such later. However, upon doing so, the result proposed by [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/integral-calculator/%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Bt%7Dxsin%5Cleft(w%5Cleft(t-x%5Cright)%5Cright)%20dx) has me a bit perplexed:
$$\int_t^0 -(-u+t)sin((ω_n(u))\;du$$
I am currently trying to understand where the constant negative sign $(-)$ before $(-u + t)$ comes from, since, surely, $(t-u)=τ\;$ as per the initial u-substitution? Does $(-u+t)$ then somehow not satisfy the original expression of $τ\;$ on its own?

I suspect that it may involve the new positioning of the internals of the parenthesis but I would very much like to hear from others on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $d \tau/ du = -1 \leadsto d \tau = -du$

Comment: If you make a change of variable $u = t - \tau$ then $du = - d\tau$ (so they say). This gives you a minus sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from the differential: if $u = t-\tau$, then $du = -d\tau$, so $d\tau = -du$.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you. I did completely neglect d-tau for the resulting change that occurs when translating to d-u. This is not my first time doing this, seeing as I am all too used to these terms "disappearing" when calculating integrals without substitution. I will be mindful of this next time.